# Perimeter on Trapezoid

Tags: geometry

Was working on this pretty intriguing geometry problem and wanted to make sure my thinking was correct and that in the end it's rather simple.  I have put what I was given on the problem and what I determined for the proof.  Any thoughts or comments?
Edit: Under given, the figure is an Isosceles trapezoid.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming things which aren't true. In fact, in this case this quadrilateral does indeed look like a trapezoid, but it is not so you will need to rethink your approach.

**Lemma.** *If $MNPQ$ is a quadrilateral it is not a trapezoid with $MN \parallel PQ$.*

*Proof.* Since we want to show that $MN \not \parallel PQ$, it suffices to show that $\angle{NQP} \neq \angle{MNQ}$. It is easy to see by dropping an altitude from $P$ to $QN$ that $\cos{\angle{NQP}} = \dfrac{14}{16} = \dfrac{7}{8}$. Then we can use Heron's formula on $\triangle{MNQ}$ to get $$[MNQ] = \sqrt{38(6)(22)(10)} = \dfrac{1}{2} 32 \cdot 28 \sin{\angle{MNQ}}\tag{1}$$
Thus from $(1)$ we obtain $\sin{\angle{MNQ}} = \dfrac{\sqrt{3135}}{112}.
$ It is then easy to see that in fact $\angle{MNQ} \neq \angle{NQP}$ by using arcsine and arccosine.

Likewise we can show that $NP \not \parallel MQ$. Therefore we are just dealing with a quadrilateral with $3$ sides that are equal.

Comment: Sorry I should have noted, the problem states the figure is an isosceles Trapezoid.

Comment: since it's given that it's an isosceles trapezoid I CAN assume that MN||PN

Comment: You have to see that such conditions fix the trapezoid. Just because the question tells you it is an isosceles trapezoid doesn't automatically mean it is. Also it is impossible that $MN \parallel PN$ without them coinciding.

Comment: "just because the question tells you it is an isosceles trapezoid doesn't automatically mean it is".. what?  We are GIVEN that the figure is an isosceles trapezoid.  By definition of an trapezoid "A trapezoid is a quadrilateral with two sides parallel", add in that it's an isosceles ....

Comment: Based on the given that you have shown: Perimeter $MNPQ = 80, MN = 32, NQ = 28, MQ \cong QP \cong PN$, $MNPQ$ is not a trapezoid. Please see my answer for the proof.

Comment: I noted in my comment that I forgot to add that it is also given that it IS a trapezoid isosceles.